# Any Alternate/ Comparative named algorithm to find Probability of an observed sequence in HMM, beside Forward-Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sequence, hidden-markov-models

Is there any other **named algorithm** to find Probability of an observed sequence, beside forward-algorithm.

Any naive approach can resolve this, but i am looking for alternate **named algorithm**.

Any idea, hint of the algorithm-name would be appreciated.

I am not looking for code here.